# What is difference b/w "[id$=MainDiv]" and "#MainDiv" in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a Div and id of this div is MainDiv Now i want to attach a click event on this div. for this i used to `[id$=MainDiv]` and `#MainDiv` to  attached a Click Event and i found that both method are working and providing "MainDiv 1"  and "MainDiv 2" result in sequence .

```
$("[id$=MainDiv]").click(function () { alert('MainDiv 1'); });
 $("#MainDiv").click(function (e) { alert('MainDiv 2'); });
```

Now a Question arise what is difference b/w both selector( `"[id$=MainDiv]`" and `"#MainDiv"`) and which one is best.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

`$("#MainDiv")` is far and away more efficient since the browser stores element ID's as special dom properties

The other version requires searching through the dom to look for an attribute which involves a lot more searching

Answer (score 0):

> Now a Question arise what is difference b/w both selector(
>   "[id$=MainDiv]" and "#MainDiv")

```
$("[id$=MainDiv]")
```

selects elements where the `id` of element ends with "MainDiv"

```
 $("#MainDiv")
```

selects single element having `id` `MainDiv` .

There could be single or multiple elements returned within collection with `$("[id$=MainDiv]")` .

There should be single element returned with `$("#MainDiv")`

> and which one is best.

Neither. Each used for different purposes . `$("#MainDiv")` to select single element . `$("[id$=MainDiv]")` to filter element or elements where `id` ends with or contains `MainDiv` ; or select multiple elements where `id` ends with or contains `MainDiv`.

`$("#MainDiv")` is specific to single element , `$("[id$=MainDiv]")` could possible return multiple elements.

See [Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)